# Sending push from 2 apps that use the same Parse App ID

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

Can I use the same Parse app from 2 different Swift apps and have specific users pushing messages to each other?

Do I need a 2nd Push (p12) certificate on either Parse or Apple Dev site? Or can both apps use the same one somehow?

My scenario is a restaurant iOS app and a customer iOS app. I need customers to send a push message to the restaurant app with every new order. I also need the restaurant manager to send a push message back to his customers with any order updates from his side. All users (restaurant owner + customers) reside on the same Parse app.

Comment: each app will have its own certificate

Comment: so I need to upload 2 different Push certificates under the same Parse App? One per iOS app?